# Get random vector in the general direction of another?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, vector

I'm trying to create a *wander to target* behavior for my enemies so that they wander, but with a purpose. After some research and effort, I determined that I would need to accomplish three things to get it to work:

- Create a basic wander behavior.
- Determine general direction to target.
- Generate random destination in general direction of target.

Now, the first step is complete for sure. I *believe* the second step is complete, but let me explain what I'm doing, as it may need adjustments to achieve the desired result. Currently, I calculate the dot product between the target's location and a directional vector (*i.e. left, right, forward, backward*), which ever calculation results in the highest dot product determines the general direction:

```
private readonly Vector3[] _compass = { Vector3.left, Vector3.right, Vector3.forward, Vector3.back };
private Vector3 GetDirectionOfTarget() {
    var result = Vector3.zero;
    var maximumDotProduct = _negativeInfinity;
    foreach (var direction in _compass) {
        var dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(Target.transform.position, direction);
        if (dotProduct > maximumDotProduct)
        {
            result = direction;
            maximumDotProduct = dotProduct;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

After calculating the general direction, I then get a random point within a unit sphere, multiply that vector by a user specified scalar value for range, and then add that to the general direction. However, after breaking that down mentally, it doesn't sound correct, because I'm going to get a random vector, then scale it out, and finally add a normalized direction to it, which just increases the range in the added direction. My code to get the new destination by applying this is:

```
var directionOfTarget = GetDirectionOfTarget();
var randomOffset = directionOfTarget + UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitSphere * MaximumRadiusFromSpawnPoint;
NavMesh.SamplePosition(transform.position + randomOffset, out NavMeshHit navHit, MaximumRadiusFromSpawnPoint, SampleNavigationArea);
```

One thought I have is to get the general direction, then manually create a random vector using that direction:

```
var directionOfTarget = GetDirectionOfTarget();

// This only works because directionOfTarget is normalized.
var x = _random.Next(0, Math.Abs(directionOfTarget.x)) * directionOfTarget.x;
var y = // same as x for y.
var z = // same as x for z.
var randomInDirection = new Vector3(x, y z);
```

However, this isn't it either because this will create movement in a box pattern instead of the more realistic approach of including movement along the `x` and `z` axes together.

---

***Update 1**: I managed to create a more **accurate** general direction through brute force:*

```
for (float x = -1.0f; x < 1.0f; x += 0.1f) {
    for (float z = -1.0f; z < 1.0f; z += 0.1f) {
        var direction = new Vector3(x, 0, z);
        var dotProduct = Vector3.Dot(Target.transform.position, direction);
        if (dotProduct > maximumDotProduct) {
            result = direction;
            maximumDotProduct = dotProduct;
        }
    }
}
```

*However, even though this produces a better result, it's expensive, and still doesn't focus the wander in the direction of the target (i.e. there's still back tracking going on).*

---

***Update 2**: After some more tinkering, I removed the brute force attempt and updated my compass to include bidirectional vectors. This significantly reduced the cost of calculating the general direction of the target. Adding to this change, I also ran with the idea of generating a random vector based on the general direction and though it's not a graceful solution in my opinion, it works:*

```
private readonly Vector3[] _compass = {
    new Vector3(-1, 0, -1), new Vector3(-1, 0, 0), new Vector3(-1, 0, 1),
    new Vector3(0, 0, -1), new Vector3(0, 0, 1),
    new Vector3(1, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 0, 1)
};

var directionOfTarget = GetDirectionOfTarget();
var x = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Math.Abs(directionOfTarget.x)) * directionOfTarget.x;
var z = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, Math.Abs(directionOfTarget.z)) * directionOfTarget.z;
var randomOffset = new Vector3(x, 0, z) * AreaSize;
NavMesh.SamplePosition(transform.position + randomOffset, out NavMeshHit navHit, AreaSize, SampleNavigationArea);
```

*Note that I simply reverted back to the original state described above for the `GetDirectionOfTarget` method.*

---

How do I get a random vector in the general direction of another?

<sub>***Note**: If there's anything I can do to clarify my question, or otherwise improve it for future readers, please leave a comment and let me know. I will gladly adjust my question as needed.*</sub>

Comment: If a random direction is added to the perfect direction it might end up as a drunk man's walk. It might be better to add a random vector to the target position and use that as the target. Then do path finding and walking to that random target for a while. Then repeat these steps. This allows you to specify the maximum randomness by setting the length of the random vector. You could even decrease it every time  in order to zoom in on the actual target.

Comment: It seems to me that you should work out what effect you want first, then the mathematics, then the code. If you do these steps in any other order, you will... wander randomly toward the solution.

Comment: @Beta the effect I want is to *wander towards a specified target*. While I achieved this per my second update, I can't help but believe in the fact that there's a smarter way to accomplish it, especially considering I'm not the best with mathematics.

Comment: Is "general direction" same as "direction", a unit-length vector U pointing from A to B? Then U=D/∥D∥, where D=B-A and ∥X∥ is the L2-norm (Euclidean length) of X. According to https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html, the ∥X∥ is `X.magnitude`, and X/∥X∥ is `X.normalized`. In other words, `U=(B-A).normalized`.※Is "Upd.1" an attempt to find the U confined to XZ-plane? Then project `U=B-A;` to the XZ plane first (set `U.y=0;`) then take `U=U.normalized;`.※Not all Upd.2 "compasses" have unit norms! ∥(1 0 1)∥=√2. Thus to get the norm of 1 reciprocate √2, e.g. ∥(±1/√2 0 ±1/√2)∥=1.